# Como exportar ReportViewer para Excel mantendo tipos dos campos?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, reportviewer, visual-studio-2010

Tenho um relatório em ViewReport no VS2010 e quando exporto para o Excel, pelo botão padrão do VS não mantém o formato dos campos. Desta forma não consigo utilizar as funções do Excel como SUM por exemplo porque todos os campos estão como Texto.

Alguém já teve algum problema parecido? Alguma dica de como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente, o ReportViewer que vem com SSRS é bem rígido - não vai poder editar com que o tipo de dado (datatype) seja algo diferente no Excel baixado. [Essa pergunta e resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3961132/1245766) explica um problema semelhante, e o autor teve que criar sua própria extensão no SSRS. Também [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13687439/1245766) teve exatamente o mesmo problema - e acabou com a mesma resposta.

Não digo que é impossível, mas é bem complicado e complexo - infelizmente!